# Collect the last element of the flow generated from the channel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

- I'm trying to collect the events generated by the ViewModel in the most efficient way.
- In order to provide this, it needs to provide the following 2 features.
- - If the view is no longer visible, it should not collect it in the fragment.
- - It should collect the only latest event as soon as view is visible, if there is a new event. otherwise it should not generate event.

The solution for the first option is easy `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted`

I couldn't do the other option.

#### MyViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
): ViewModel() {

    private val eventChannel = Channel<String>(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED)
    val eventFlow = eventChannel.receiveAsFlow()


    fun triggerEvent(event: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            eventChannel.send(event)
        }
    }

}
```

#### MyFragmant:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding.buttonGoScanProductFragment.setOnClickListener {
            
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.triggerEvent(generateUniqueString(10))
                delay(5000)
                viewModel.triggerEvent(generateUniqueString(10))
                delay(5000)
                viewModel.triggerEvent(generateUniqueString(10))
                delay(5000)
                viewModel.triggerEvent(generateUniqueString(10))
                delay(5000)
                viewModel.triggerEvent(generateUniqueString(10))
                delay(5000)
                viewModel.triggerEvent(generateUniqueString(10))
                delay(5000)
            }
        }


        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.eventFlow.collectLatest{
                Timber.d("Event collected: $it")
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

To summarize the problem, How can I make the Fragment collect only the most recently generated event?

> The reason I don't use Sharedflow is that, as far as i know when the view is visible it won't provide the last event.

Comment: Why not use a `StateFlow` and access the current `.value`?

Comment: @Joffrey i want an event to be generated if there is a change in the event after view is visible. The event collected in StateFlow can be collected again.

Comment: Channel is not suitable for unskippable events because values can be dropped if they are in flight while a coroutine gets cancelled. I would use StateFlow with an additional consumed version of the event. So when you receive the event, only process if it’s not consumed, and feed back to ViewModel that it is now consumed. ViewModel then updates the state flow to a consumed event.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Will the last collected event not be collected again when the View is visible? it is not clear. Lets say viewmodel receive new unique event and updates the stateflow and after that this event collected in view. But if the app goes to background and returns back, it will collect again the same event.

Comment: It won't collect the same event again if you immediately replace the event with a "consumed event" in the same flow.